# Master View Details with MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM - WPF Browser Application application using Entity Framework 6.
I have tried to select a `supplierDataGrid` row and display the Products related in another datagrid. But it doesn't work. The application freezes when I select a row. Thanks for your help!

#### ViewModelBase

```
public class CommandBase<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region "INotifyPropertyChanged members"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //This routine is called each time a property value has been set. 
    //This will //cause an event to notify WPF via data-binding that a change has occurred. 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    private ObservableCollection<T> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            if (collection == null)
            {
                Get();
            }
            return collection;
        }
        set { collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection"); }
    }

    private T _selected;
    public T Selected
    {
        get {
            if(_selected != null)
            GetSub();
            return _selected; 
            }
        set { _selected = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
    }

    private ICommand getCommand;
    private ICommand saveCommand;
    private ICommand removeCommand;
    private ICommand getSubCommand;

    protected virtual void Save()
    {
        //return true;
    }
    protected virtual bool CanSave()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get
        {
           // return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(Delete,CanDelete));
            return removeCommand ?? (removeCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Delete(), p => this.CanDelete()));

        }
    }

    protected virtual void Delete()
    { }

    protected virtual bool CanDelete()
    {
        if (Selected != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public ICommand GetSubCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return getSubCommand ?? (getSubCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.GetSub(), p => this.CanGetSub()));
        }
    }

    protected virtual async Task GetSub()
    {
        await Task.Delay(0); 
    }


    protected virtual bool CanGetSub()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class SupplierViewModel : CommandBase<foodSupplier>
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    protected override void Get()
    {
        ctx.foodSuppliers.ToList().ForEach(supplier => ctx.foodSuppliers.Local.Add(supplier));
        Collection = ctx.foodSuppliers.Local;
    }
    protected override bool CanGet()
    {
        return true;
    }
    protected override void Save()
    {
        foreach (foodSupplier item in Collection)
        {
            if (ctx.Entry(item).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added)
            {
                ctx.foodSuppliers.Add(item);
            }
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected override void Delete()
    {
        var id = Selected;
        var supp = (from s in ctx.foodSuppliers
                where s.idfoodSupplier == id.idfoodSupplier
                select s).SingleOrDefault();
        ctx.foodSuppliers.Remove(supp);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Collection.Remove(supp);
    }
    protected virtual bool CanDelete()
    {
        return true;
    }

     protected override async Task GetSub()
    {

        var supplier = Selected;
        var pro = await (from p in ctx.products
                         where p.supplier == supplier.idfoodSupplier
                         select p).ToListAsync();

        Products = pro;

    }

    private IList<product> _products;

    public IList<product> Products
    {
        get
        {

            return _products;

        }
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }
}
```

#### View

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          Margin="5"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumn"
                            Header="Supplier"
                            Binding="{Binding idfoodSupplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Visibility="Hidden" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier"
                            Binding="{Binding supplier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
<Button Height="Auto"
        Width="Auto"
        Content="Delete"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" />
```

Comment: One funny thing about WPF freezed, try to pause your debug execution during freeze sometime shows you the exact location of the problem location. And, for your view model, maybe you can try refactor all EF operation out to a helper/service class and then inject the service into your viewmodel's constructor. See if it's neater.

Comment: where's ur GetCommand implementation by the way ?

Comment: Please run your debugger and figure out where the execution halts.

Comment: I didn't put the GetCommand in the code, but it works.

Comment: the execution stops at var pro = (from p in ctx.products
                   where p.supplier == supplier.idfoodSupplier
                   select p).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: the program freezes, because you have infinite recursion. Selected getter call GetSub, it calls getter of Selected it call GetSub, etc...
I recommend you to call GetSub in Selected setter, but some additional refactoring may be needed.

TIP: when somethig freezes, pause the program in visual studio and take a look at callstack window. You would immediatelly know whats going on in this case. Maybe you will need to switch to Main thread in Threads window (Ctrl+Alt+H) after you press pause button.

Comment: In general, yes. Specifically in this case, no. The thing is, that if you used the GetSub method somewhere else than the command, you won't be able to await it, or  use try/catch or using statement in the caller. The other thing is, that it may be very usefull to have IsRunning property on the AsyncCommand, so you can for example disable the button while it is running. But that's topic for another question.

Comment: For now the program freezes at var supplier = Selected, so the query returns nothing.